# Why is query builder passing wrong parameters in my query?

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I am running following query using query buider

when I print the query 2nd place parmeter is being passed where 1st paramerter should be passed please anyone can explain what am I doing wrong here?

```js
const queryRunner: QueryRunner = getConnection().createQueryRunner();

  await queryRunner.startTransaction();

  try {
    //other queries here deleted for simplicity
    await queryRunner.manager
      .getRepository(User)
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .update(User)
      .set({ status: UserStatus.INACTIVE }) // UserStatus is enum
      .where("organizationId IN(:...ids)", { ids: organizations })
      .printSql()
      .execute();

    await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
  } catch (err) {
    await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
    console.log("=====Rollback=====");
  } finally {
    await queryRunner.release();
  }
```

output:

```sql
UPDATE "users" SET "status" = $2 WHERE "organizationId" IN($2, $3, $4, $5) -- PARAMETERS: ["INACTIVE",32,36,35,34]
```

Comment: status should be $1

Comment: @madflow yes it should be but I am getting this query as output

Comment: `IN(:...ids)` looks strange to me. `IN(:ids)` should be sufficient, if `organizations` is a number array. Maybe this solves the problem?

Comment: @hendra `IN(:...ids)` is for spreading number array in `IN` clause with out it query looks like `UPDATE "users" SET "status" = $2 WHERE "organizationId" IN($2) -- PARAMETERS: ["Inactive",[4,49]]` when what I need is `UPDATE "users" SET "status" = $1 WHERE "organizationId" IN($2,$3) -- PARAMETERS: ["Inactive",4,49]`

Comment: Try ```.where("organizationId IN (:...ids)", { ids: organizations })```. Space between ```IN``` and (...)

Comment: @CarloCorradini   No luck..

Comment: Super strange, post an issue on GitHub.

Comment: yes I did @CarloCorradini let's see what comes out

Comment: @AnuragParmar Since you've solved the issue on GitHub, can you post the correct answer and accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the real issue was not with the code I wrote but rather it was a bug in `typeorm` version `0.2.25` and it is fixed in the latest release of the library.

For detailed overview see here: [Github issues](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7988).

Thank you.